# extension of bsxfun to cater to particular indices in a matrix

Tags: matlab, image-processing, max, min, bsxfun

I have a problem. I am trying to implement this short piece of code.
[image]

The basic steps I have already done. Please check my code below:

```
clc;clear all;close all;
A=round(-3+(6).*rand(5,5));
B=round(-3+(6).*rand(5,5));
%//The check matrix stores the conditions present on the right side of the equation.
check = A.*B
%//upd_max and upd_min are the given as the del_max and del_min in the equation
upd_max = 0.5;
upd_min = 0.1;
%//eta_plus and eta_minus are denoted as nplus and nminus
nplus = 1.2;
nminus = 0.5;
%del_(k-1)_i matrix is given as update_mat
update_mat = (0.1+(0.4).*rand(size(check))).*ones(size(check))
update_new = update_mat.*(check==0) +  bsxfun(@min,(nplus.*update_mat.*(check>0)),upd_max)...
             + bsxfun(@max,nminus.*(update_mat.*(check<0)),upd_min)
```

I am giving below a sample result of my piece of code:

```
check =

     2    -6     0    -1     2
    -3    -4     3    -3     4
     0     2    -2     6     0
     2    -1    -4    -1    -3
    -2    -4    -3     0     6


update_mat =

    0.4102    0.4173    0.1126    0.2268    0.4964
    0.4622    0.3750    0.4282    0.3422    0.1495
    0.4760    0.3820    0.2903    0.3143    0.1473
    0.3603    0.2861    0.3122    0.3527    0.2908
    0.3602    0.3696    0.3220    0.2046    0.4746
update_new =

    0.5922    0.2087    0.2126    0.1134    0.6000
    0.2311    0.1875    0.6000    0.1711    0.2794
    0.5760    0.5584    0.1452    0.4772    0.2473
    0.5324    0.1431    0.1561    0.1763    0.1454
    0.1801    0.1848    0.1610    0.3046    0.6000
```

However this answer is not correct!! To explain I am dividing my answer into three parts:

```
update_mat.*(check==0)

ans =

         0         0    0.1126         0         0
         0         0         0         0         0
    0.4760         0         0         0    0.1473
         0         0         0         0         0
         0         0         0    0.2046         0

bsxfun(@min,(nplus.*update_mat.*(check>0)),upd_max)

ans =

    0.4922         0         0         0    0.5000
         0         0    0.5000         0    0.1794
         0    0.4584         0    0.3772         0
    0.4324         0         0         0         0
         0         0         0         0    0.5000
```

As can be seen clearly the **`first` two terms are correct**  . However the third term is wrong.
The third term comes as this :

```
bsxfun(@max,nminus.*(update_mat.*(check<0)),upd_min)

ans =

    0.1000    0.2087    0.1000    0.1134    0.1000
    0.2311    0.1875    0.1000    0.1711    0.1000
    0.1000    0.1000    0.1452    0.1000    0.1000
    0.1000    0.1431    0.1561    0.1763    0.1454
    0.1801    0.1848    0.1610    0.1000    0.1000
```

The correct third term should give me

```
     0    0.2087         0    0.1134         0
0.2311    0.1875         0    0.1711         0
     0         0    0.1452         0         0
     0    0.1431    0.1561    0.1763         0
0.1801    0.1848    0.1610         0    0.1000
```

**I want the bsxfun to compute the element wise maximum** only for the non-zero elements of the matrix `nminus.*(update_mat.*(check<0))` and not the whole matrices. Is it possible to do so?

Thanks in advance! PS: Please give ideas for better optimized code.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You don't need bsxfun since you're dealing with a scalar, you just need logical indexing:

```
 M=nminus.*(update_mat.*(check<0))
 M((~~M) & (M < upd_min)) = upd_min   %// ~~M is the same as M~=0
```

(btw this assumes that for your example data you made a mistake in the second last row of the last column where you have `0` but I think you want `0.1454`)

Comment: I understand your idea and it works too! but cant I use bsxfun to do it ? As I understand it is significantly faster.

Comment: @roni that's not what bsxfun does. I highly highly doubt it would be faster than logical indexing. It is often faster than using `repmat` or loops but when you're dealing with a scalar, it's pointless. This is the way to go.

Comment: @roni Bsxfun is used when you need to expand **vectors** to match dimensions. With scalars is pointless and adds to the overhead.

Comment: Just to add to what @OlegKomarov has said, Matlab **automatically** expands scalars for you.